# While installing nltk package getting ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sqlite3'

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, nltk, rhel7

Getting below error while running a code snippet which has nltk dependencies.

Manually installed `python 3.6.5` and using it in the virtual enviornment 
The OS (`Red Hat Linux 7.4-Maipo`) has `python 2.7.4` installed in it.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "FLASK_RECOMMENDER_VER_1_1.py", line 15, in <module>
    import nltk
  File "/home/ec2-user/RecommenderEngine/re_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/__init__.py", line 137, in <module>
    from nltk.stem import *
  File "/home/ec2-user/RecommenderEngine/re_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/stem/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer
  File "/home/ec2-user/RecommenderEngine/re_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/stem/snowball.py", line 32, in <module>
    from nltk.corpus import stopwords
  File "/home/ec2-user/RecommenderEngine/re_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/corpus/__init__.py", line 66, in <module>
    from nltk.corpus.reader import *
  File "/home/ec2-user/RecommenderEngine/re_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/corpus/reader/__init__.py", line 105, in <module>
    from nltk.corpus.reader.panlex_lite import *
  File "/home/ec2-user/RecommenderEngine/re_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/corpus/reader/panlex_lite.py", line 15, in <module>
    import sqlite3
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sqlite3'
```

Tried below solution but it didn't help (used yum and pip instead) :

[solution 1](https://github.com/sloria/TextBlob/issues/173)

```
sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
```

(Or you can install more packages as suggested on the pyenv wiki:
 `apt-get install -y make build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev wget curl llvm libncurses5-dev xz-utils tk-dev`

Now in the downloaded python source rebuild and install python with the following command: ./configure --enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions && make && sudo make install.

My Attempt throwing below error :

```
Collecting libsqlite3-dev
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement libsqlite3-dev (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for libsqlite3-dev
```

Answer (score 9):

Answering my own question.

Finally fixed the issue by Installing sqlite-devel package :

```
yum install sqlite-devel
```

and re-installing the python as follows:

```
sudo wget http://python.org/ftp/python/3.6.5/Python-3.6.5.tar.xz
tar xf Python-3.6.5.tar.xz
cd Python-3.6.5
sudo ./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-shared LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath /usr/local/lib" 
sudo ./configure --enable-optimizations
sudo make && sudo make altinstall
```

Comment: Just wanted to add that this fixed my virtual python environments as well, ty

Comment: it took a lot of time to execute, did anyone face this?

Comment: @jht how long do you mean?  I didn't enable optimizations, and it took my computer on the order of a couple minutes to compile and link everything.  I think that's probably pretty reasonable, it may be a bit longer with optimizations though.